# How to filter a table that has been loaded with JSON data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, html-table

I'm trying to filter information from a table that has been loaded with JSON data.
What I'm trying to do is to put the inputs and then filter the table when I press the button. Here is the important part of my html file:

```
<form role="search" class="search-form" style="flex-grow:1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dpt">Partida:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dpt">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dtn">Destino:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dtn">
        </div>
        <div class="row-md">
            <button class="Search" onclick=searchDepartures()>Procurar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container" style="width: 50%; overflow: hidden; float: right;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="routes_table" style="width: 100%;">
        <thread>
            <tr>
                <th>Partidas</th>
                <th>Destinos</th>
            </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON("locations.json", function (data) {
    var routes_data = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        routes_data += '<tr>';
        routes_data += '<td>' + value.departure + '</td>';
        routes_data += '<td>' + value.arrival + '</td>';
        routes_data += '</tr>';
    })
    $(routes_table).append(routes_data);
});

$.getJSON("locationsEN.json", function (data) {
    var routes_data = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        routes_data += '<tr>';
        routes_data += '<td>' + value.departure + '</td>';
        routes_data += '<td>' + value.arrival + '</td>';
        routes_data += '</tr>';
    })
});

function searchDepartures() {
    var results = [];
    var searchField = value.departure;
    var searchVal = "#dpt";
    for (var i=0 ; i < routes_data.length ; i++)
    {
        if (routes_data[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
            results.push(routes_data[i]);
            $(routes_table).append(routes_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Also my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "departure": "Beja",
    "arrival": "Lisboa"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "departure": "Lisboa",
    "arrival": "Beja"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "departure": "Beja",
    "arrival": "Évora"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "departure": "Évora",
    "arrival": "Beja"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "departure": "Beja",
    "arrival": "Faro"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "departure": "Faro",
    "arrival": "Beja"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "departure": "Beja",
    "arrival": "Setúbal"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "departure": "Setúbal",
    "arrival": "Beja"
  }
]
```

So far nothing as worked except putting the whole table in, which is expected when the inputs are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all

```
$(routes_table).append(routes_data);
```

With

```
$('#routes_table').append(routes_data);
```

You don't have routes_table variable, but you have routes_table ID on table

Additionaly you have problems with variable scopes, getting element by id and others, check this out:

```
var json = [];
$.getJSON("locations.json", function (data) {
    var routes_data = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        routes_data += '<tr>';
        routes_data += '<td>' + value.departure + '</td>';
        routes_data += '<td>' + value.arrival + '</td>';
        routes_data += '</tr>';
    })
    json = data;
    $('#routes_table tbody').append(routes_data);
});

function searchDepartures() {
    var results = [];
    var searchField = "departure";
    var searchVal = document.getElementById('dtn').value;
    $('#routes_table tbody').html('');
    for (var i=0 ; i < json.length ; i++)
    {
        if (json[i][searchField] == searchVal) {

          var newroutes_data = '';
            newroutes_data += '<tr>';
            newroutes_data += '<td>' + json[i].departure + '</td>';
            newroutes_data += '<td>' + json[i].arrival + '</td>';
            newroutes_data += '</tr>';


            results.push(newroutes_data);
            $('#routes_table tbody').append(newroutes_data);
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Fix your html table - not thread but thead:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Partidas</th>
        <th>Destinos</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference, still can't search the table, sorry

Comment: @NightShadowSaintPT you are trying to use variable inside getjson and accessing searchField = value.departure, where there is no value object. Check my updated answer

Comment: i think we are getting progress, but the table is still not updating

Comment: @NightShadowSaintPT change appends to: `$('#routes_table tbody').append(routes_data);`  I didn't noticed that you have thead and tbody, this should work

Comment: did the fixes, still the same result, the button just kind of reloads the page

Comment: i think it has something to do with the button because i tried commenting the filtering code and using the code above on the button and i still did not get a result, as it should show the whole list

Comment: @NightShadowSaintPT I've just noticed whole list of bugs in your code, take a look at working example (I commented out getjson, uncomment) and adapt it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjEWzv I updated answer too